How to highlight mismatching values between sheets in Tableau?
I have two sheets in Tableau that both contain a list of names. I want to highlight the mismatching values (or even matching values if that's easier) between the sheets. Both sheets use the same data source and field. The solution doesn't have to be on two different sheets if there's a way to do it all in one, I was just having a hard time figuring that out since they use the same field name. All help is appreciated.!
I have tried using dual axis, calculated fields, actions, etc. but nothing seems to be working. Been really frustrated with this especially because I'm used to conditional formatting in Excel where this would be a simple button press.
Expected Results:
Sheet 1                                    Sheet 2
|   Name   |                               |   Name   |
| -------- |                               | -------- |
| Aliyah   |                               | Aliyah   |
| Anna     |                               | Anna     |
| Bert     |                               | Bert     |
| James    | NOT A MATCH                   | John     |
| Jason    | NOT A MATCH                   | Patrick  |
| John     |
| Patrick  |


I believe you can do this with a SELF JOIN.  There's an example here and another here

Tableau has a versatile feature called sets that will be useful for this. If you create two sets of names, based on the same field, then you can easily display lists of names and highlight those that are either in the intersection, union, or set difference of the two sets.  It takes a bit to learn all the different ways to use Tableau sets, so take some time to experiment on something simple and look for some online examples, videos and blogs on the feature.

on what condition you are differentiating the sheet1 and sheet2.
based on that condition create a calculated field like this
Sheet 1                                    Sheet 2
|   Name   |   new field                   |   Name   |
| -------  |   ------------                | -------- |
| Aliyah   |       0                       | Aliyah   |
| Anna     |       0                       | Anna     |
| Bert     |       0                       | Bert     |
| James    |       1                       | John     |
| Jason    |       1                       | Patrick  |

put that calculated field in color marks

What is the calculated field?

'new filed' is the calculated field. this represents the difference between those 2 sheets

Yes, but how would you calculate that, what is the formula you are using to get those numbers? The question states that both sheets use the same field for their data, how is this addressed?

He hasn't specified how the two sheets have different names, as they're sourced from the same Datasource. This suggests each sheet has a unique filter applied at the calculation level, so he understands how they differ. Based on this, he should create a new field and use it for coloring.

All I am saying is we can't assume that, and then give an answer based off the assumption unless we specify it or at least provide and example. That way if someone else is having the same problem it keeps us from having to write the same answer twice. See this article for best practice.
